# Email 2 Case trigger

Tags: trigger, email2case, debug

Trying to setup a trigger to fire on the EmailMessage for Email to case to set a few custom required fields we have on case. I've seen other examples of people  using what I have below, but I can't get this trigger to fire and show up in my debug logs. Any ideas? It's a developer org but the Email2Case is setup and working. I receive an email response that says we are missing required fields on my case.

> The following errors were encountered while processing an incoming email:
>   REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING : Required fields are missing: [Service]

```
trigger TestEmail2Case on EmailMessage (before insert, before update) {
system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'omg:');    }
```

Edit for clarity:
We are using the on demand service of Email2Case and not the client based version.

Service is a custom field we created, it's a lookup to a custom object.

Comment: Are you using the on-demand version or the older client version?

Comment: (1) are you looking in the right place for the debug logs - they may not be under your name as you might not be the running user. (2) `Service` is not a field on `Case` or `EmailMessage` per the doc

Comment: We are using the on-demand version. Sorry for not specifying, I will update my comment. In regards to not looking in the right place, that is extremely possible! I'm probably not the running user, where do I go to see debug logs of the platform? Service for us is a custom field on case that we set to required. It's a lookup to a service custom object we created.

Comment: (1) I believe the Case object has to be inserted by SFDC before the `EmailMessage` is inserted and its trigger fired.  Hence `Service` should have a default value in Case

Comment: Ahh I see, that would explain why no matter what I try with a trigger it doesn't seem to update the service__c field in case before it fails. As far as having a default value with a lookup, all I could find was this: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000007PidAAE so I guess it's not really possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that it's still an idea, cases having custom required fields cause Email to case failure : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000K1D9AAK

I suggest that you mark your Service__c field as *not required* then create a validation rule that throws an error everytime the field is empty

Comment: Unless i'm not following, this won't work. For us the Service__c field is a required field on the case. Doing a trigger on Case (before insert / before update) isn't early enough as validation is done in order before insert / update. Doing a trigger on Email (before insert / before update) also doesn't fire (see crop1645's message above) because I believe he is correct as the order of operations (validation for the case is done before any triggers). I think the problem is making a lookup required on cases and lookup's not supporting a default value.

Comment: A *before insert* trigger on Case would solve the validation problem, since the case isn't yet inserted you can hardcode a service value based on the origin of the case

Comment: So I just tried it and it still maybe a problem with the email2case not running as me so I don't see debug logs for it. But my code: trigger UpdateServiceForEmail2Case ON Case (before INSERT, before UPDATE) {
   system.debug('Entered UpdateServiceForEmail2Case');
}  doesn't trigger when I send in an email  ... also the documentation makes me believe that validation is done before before triggers lol  : "Required values at the layout level and field-definition level" https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm

Comment: Hi I checked and indeed you're right ! there's a limitation in Salesforce as you can see : cases having custom required values cause problems with email to case : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000K1D9AAK

Comment: Ahh there it is, good catch with the link. I'm not sure what the appropriate response here is but if you make that idea link an answer i'll mark it as best answer.